# Line break support in parser (TCL)

Tags: parsing, tcl

So, I have a parser, written in TCL. There are many commands in the parsing file. Now, I need to add support for line breaks.
For ex.

```
my_command \
  arg1 \
  arg2 \
  arg3
```

I have something like this.

```
while { ! [eof $currentFileDescriptor] } {
            set line [gets $currentFileDescriptor]
            set lst [lindex [regexp -all -inline {^(\s*(\S*)\s*)*(\{(.*)\})?(\s*(\S*)\s*)*$} $line] 0]
            set tok [string toupper [lindex $lst 0]]
            switch -glob $tok {
              "\#*" { }
              "MY_COMMAND_1" { parseMyCommand1 $handler $lst }
              .....#other commands  }
            }
            incr lnum
        }
```

I am looking for an optimal and effective solution.

Comment: Could you highlight your question please? As of right now, I cannot see any question.

Comment: If line ends with backslash, add on the next line (if available)?

Comment: If line ends with backslash, remove the backslash and append next line without backspaces to the current line. Repeat, until the last character of current line is a backslash. For example, the mentioned "my_command" in the question should be equivalent to the following, "my_command arg1 arg2 arg3"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have defined a domain specific language (DSL) with the parsing implemented in Tcl. You may as well use the Tcl parsing itself to deal with things like line continuation and quote handling. The method to do this is to create a safe interpreter and in the safe interpreter only provide the commands required for your DSL. You then interpret your config file in the safe child interpreter. The [wiki page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1477) has some examples.

The advantage of this method is that the parsing is handled by the normal Tcl parser. However you can be in complete control of what commands are exposed in the safe interpreter. You can also control the amount of resources it can use (stack and memory) and limit it's visibility of the filesystem or network.

If you don't want to get into this then you just need to implement recognition of backslashed newlines and buffer such lines until you have a complete line. Something like the following (untested):

```
set linenum 0
set buffer ""
while {[gets $input line] != -1} {
    incr linenum
    if {[regexp {\\$} $line]} {
        append buffer [string range $line 0 end-1]
        continue
    } else {
        append buffer $line
    }
    ParseCompleteLine $linenum $buffer
    set buffer ""
}
```